# disable future dates in angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am unable to disable future dates.

Using [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="user.join_date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }"    />
```

Tried adding `this.future = false;` inside `DateObject()` of directive without any success...

**EDIT**

Found that I can use `before-render` and then make `selectable=false;` for future dates.

Trying to implement.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it.

Used `beforeRender` function and disable future dates comparing `utcDateValue` with current date.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.beforeRender = function ($dates) {
    /* disable future dates */
    for(var i=0; i<$dates.length;i++) {
       if(new Date().getTime() < $dates[i].utcDateValue) {
          $dates[i].selectable = false;
       }
    }                
};
```

Added `data-before-render="beforeRender($dates)"` as well

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="user.join_date" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" data-before-render="beforeRender($dates)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow only future

I needed the exact opposite requirement that is slightly more complicated, to allow only future date you need to consider the argument $view

Javascript:

```
$scope.futureOnlyBeforeRender = function($view, $dates) {
// $view values: year, month, day, hour, minute
var currentDate = new Date();
// set the current date according to the view
switch($view){
    case 'year': currentDate.setYear(currentDate.getYear() - 1); break;
    case 'month': currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 1); break;
    case 'day': currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1); break;
    case 'hour': currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 1); break;
    case 'minute': currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() - 1); break;
}
// apply ot the dates
$dates.filter(function (date) {
    return date.utcDateValue < currentDate.getTime();
}).forEach(function (date) {
    date.selectable = false;
})
```

};

HTML:

```
data-before-render="futureOnlyBeforeRender($view, $dates)"
```